# How to order by specific group in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to query like this:

Display all details for Employees in the order of the follow jobs: DIRECTOR, SUPERVISOR,ENGINEER and CLERK.

The Employees table structure is like this:

(**Employee_ID**,FirstName,LastName,Job_ID)

The Jobs tablet structure is like this:

(**Job_ID**,Job_Title,Min_Salary,Max_Salary)

How can I group by specific group like this?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You don't need to group--you need to order.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
      * 
  from employees employees
  join jobs jobs
    on employees.job_id = jobs.job_id
 order by case
         when job_title = 'DIRECTOR' then
          1
         when job_title = 'SUPERVISOR' then
          2
         when job_title = 'ENGINEER' then
          3
         when job_title = 'CLERK' then
          4
         else
          0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case
         when job_title = 'DIRECTOR' then
          1
         when job_title = 'SUPERVISOR' then
          2
         when job_title = 'ENGINEER' then
          3
         when job_title = 'CLERK' then
          4
         else
          0
       end as seq,
       employees.*,
       jobs.*
  from employees
  join jobs
    on employees.job_id = jobs.job_id
 order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL (as implied by the "mysqli" tag), then use the field function:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN
     Job J
     ON J.Job_ID = E.Job_ID
ORDER BY field(J.Job_Title, 'DIRECTOR', 'SUPERVISOR', 'ENGINEER', 'CLERK');
```